# React Configuration in multiple deployments

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, create-react-app

We want to deploy the same react web app on our data center and in the cloud. Each deployment has different settings like the base  url the API is located and other configurations. Which is the best way to inject this info? At building time? Is there a file like web.config in .net but for react apps?

Answer (score 1):

If you use create-react-app, you can use [Environment Variables](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/).

Just define variables in your CI and use it like this:

```js
const API_HOST = process.env.REACT_APP_API_HOST;
```

You also able to define it inside the [.env](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#what-other-env-files-can-be-used) file like this:

```sh
REACT_APP_API_HOST = my-api-path.com
```

Comment: I use create-react-app but the app is hosted in S3, and I thinks there is no environment variables there.

Comment: Sure. You should define variables, make a build and publish this build wherever you want. You can use different variables to make different builds.